# Pandas rewriting columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file. It has several columns with data and two columns have the same names. When I get a pandas frame with the data from this file, it turns out that the columns with the same names exist in a single instance. That is, one of the columns is rewritten.

I get data using `pd.read_table`, where pd is pandas

I watched the documentation of the pandas but did not find the option that suited me. Please tell me there is some attribute when creating a frame with data that takes into account the presence of identical columns.

Sorry for my English and thanks a lot.

Comment: can you show your data file?

Comment: What is your version of pandas?

Comment: pandas version 0.18.0

Answer (score 0):

I think last version of pandas (`0.19.2`) add `.number` to same column names:

```
temp=u"""A;A;B;B
1;1;1;1
2;3;1;2"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (df)
   A  A.1  B  B.1
0  1    1  1    1
1  2    3  1    2
```

But is possible set names by custom list:

```
temp=u"""A;A;B;B
1;1;1;1
2;3;1;2"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep=";", names= ['w','e','r','t'])
print (df)
   w  e  r  t
0  A  A  B  B
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  3  1  2
```

Comment: If use my sample, your output is different?

Comment: yeah, your sample is working. pandas 0.18.0 add .number to same columns name too. Now trying with big file. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: Try it, because I never seen it data are overwritten. Give me know hopw it works. thanks.

Comment: For a large file the problem remains. At what I tried the same example with `pd.read_table` and there too numbers are added to the columns with the same name. very strange

Comment: Maybe problem with memory :(

Comment: Hmm, maybe with memory but i don't understand why. And maybe this problem arises because of the data format in the file. That is, suddenly the data is so arranged that for some reason the header of one of the columns is overwritten?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know. Maybe some kind of bug. But is possible set name manually, I add solution for it. Can you check it?

Comment: i got it. if header names divide by '\n' it overwritting columns

Comment: I am not sure if understand, `new line chars` are in column names?

Comment: yes. if your column names in one line in file everything is fine, pandas add .number to columns with the same name. But when column name located on different lines, pandas rewrite columns

Comment: So possible solution is find when data have `\n` and then skip this number of rows.  For read only a few rows use `df = pd.read_csv('file', nrows=3, header=None)` .

Comment: Yes thank you. Did something similar with some changes, worked